# How to access the field of a model which sits in 2 ForeignKey connections to the model, from where it being accessed?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have 3 models which are chain connected to each other via ForeignKey and inside the Lesson model I want to create a file path to upload videos to like this courses/COURSE_NAME/SECTION_NAME, where uppercase letters are variables which should be replaced with the actual course name and section name, I don't have any problems with accessing the section name using `section.name`, but when I try to access the course name using the same approach `section.course.name` I get an error. Here is my models code:

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ...

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sections')
    ...

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=f'courses/{section.course.name}/{section.name}/')
```

Error occurs in this part of code:

```py
video = models.FileField(upload_to=f'courses/{section.course.name}/{section.name}/')
```

Here's the error message that I get:

```
video = models.FileField(upload_to=f'courses/{section.course.name}/{section.name}/')
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'course'
```

Thanks in advance!!!

**Edit 1:**

So in process of thinking how to do this I came up with idea maybe there's a way to create a set_up method which will be run after the initialization of a course foreign key but before video file field. This set up method can treat `self` like you would treat an instance of a Lesson class so I tried to implement this using an `__init__` method:

```py
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section_id = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.section_id = self.section.id
        super(Lesson, self).__init__(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

    video = models.FileField(upload_to=f'courses/{section_id}/')
```

Project runs normally but when I go to the admin pannel and try to edit Lesson database server gives me this error:

```
'Lesson' object has no attribute '_state'
```

I did my research and found out that's because you can't just call an **init** method of models.Model. At least that's how I understood it.

Comment: @user11717481 I edited the question and specified what I actually want to do in this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
x = Lesson.objects.get(pk=1)

print('SECTION_NAME', x.section)
print('COURSE_NAME', x.section.course)
```

**Update 19.12.2022**

Based on the Lesson model and its pk, I tried to get data from the Section model, as follows, the first option with one value, the second with several:

```
aaa = Section.objects.filter(lesson__pk=1).all()
print('name', aaa)
print('course', aaa[0].course)

bbb = Section.objects.filter(lesson__pk__in=[1, 2]).all()
print('QuerySet more than one value', bbb)
for a in bbb:
  print('id', a.id, 'course', a.course)
```

**Update 24.12.2022**

Perhaps the following will help you: pass the result returned by the function to [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

```
def directory(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.section.name, instance.section.course, filename)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=directory, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: So I checked this and it works but I need to get the course name from inside of the Lesson class, when I try to use pretty much the same approach inside the Lesson class `Section.objects.get(pk = section.pk).course.name` I get this error `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: @iljuhenson updated the response of getting data from the model Section.

Comment: That's a good method, thank you I learnt something new. But still this code you are suggesting me sits outside of the lesson class or model, and I need this inside the lesson model so that I could dynamically set the path to the video depending on the course this video corresponds to

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been looking for, thank you